# vim plugins blogger.vim does not work, is it metarw?

Tags: vim, plugins, blogger

I want to use [blogger.vim](https://github.com/ujihisa/blogger.vim) and installed it. But it does not work. I checked the ruby files and they work:

> ruby blogger.rb list 1234567

So I think the error could be on the metarw side. And try to do a smoketest with metarw to access https://github.com/jerik/CiRMes/blob/master/README.md. inside vim, but nothing happens.

edit git:jerik/CiRMes/blob/master/README.md

- How do I get `blogger.vim` working?
- How can I do a smoketest with `metarw`?

Here are is my vim setup accoring to `blogger.vim` and `metarw`

```
jerik .vim $ find . | egrep -r "metarw|blogger"
./autoload/blogger.rb
./autoload/blogger.vim
./autoload/metarw.vim
./doc/metarw.txt
./plugin/metarw.vim
./syntax/metarw.vim
```

And my .vimrc

```
let g:blogger_blogid = '1234567'
let g:blogger_email = 'gmail@gmail.com'
let g:blogger_pass = '121212'
let g:blogger_ruby_path =expand( '/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby' )
```

Comment: Not sure if it's related but you don't have a closing `'` after your password here.

Comment: @KeithSmiley was a correction error. is correct on my .vimrc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the Install section of blogger.vim's README.md](https://github.com/ujihisa/blogger.vim/blob/befa35a3d99b471defd89c79fb7e671e7bd73efd/README.md#install):

```
$ cp autoload/metarw/blogger.vim ~/.vim/autoload/metarw/
$ cp autoload/metarw/blogger.rb ~/.vim/autoload/metarw/
```

But you copied blogger.vim's files directly under `autoload/` instead of `autoload/metarw/`.
That's why blogger.vim doesn't work.  You didn't install the plugin correctly.

If you install the plugin correctly, try `:e blogger:list` to test everything works fine.

Comment: Ahhh. Thanks, will check tomorrow!